# Finding value of object id

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, variables

I have created an action result that allows restuarant to save their menu to a database. My issue is that I need to use the `menuID` for another controller but when I run the code the the variable `menuID` is always 0 instead of the value that was just added to the database.

Any help would be grateful.

**Create Menu Action Result**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(MenuViewModel model)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
          var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
          using (var objCtx = new ApplicationDbContext())
          {
               var currentrestaurant = (from r in objCtx.Restaurants
                                        where r.UserID == currentUser.Id
                                        select r).First<Restaurant>().id;
               var menu = new Menu() { Name = model.Name, Restaurantid = currentrestaurant };
               var menuID = menu.Id;
               db.Menus.Add(menu);
               db.SaveChanges();
               return RedirectToAction("Create", "Meal", new { MenudID = menuID});
          }
      }
      return View();
}
```

Comment: you just create a Menu instance and didn't give any value to Id property.So what would you expect to happen ?

Comment: uhm not to sure as its been a while since ive used linq like this but doesnt it execute and return the ID, so wouldnt moving                     var menuID = menu.Id; to after the save change work?

Comment: @Selman22 Well it could be using property shenanigans to do it, there's no way to answer this question without more information.

Comment: How would I get the Id of the Menu instance? It is an auto incremented int in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the ID is generated in database. If this is the case `menu.Id` will have the actual value *after* you save the object to DB, not before. So you need to reorder your code:

```
var menu = new Menu() { Name = model.Name, Restaurantid = currentrestaurant };
db.Menus.Add(menu);
db.SaveChanges();

return RedirectToAction("Create", "Meal", new { MenudID = menu.Id});
```

Side note. Make sure parameter in the last line is spelled correctly - shouldn't it be `MenuID` instead of `MenudID`?